# Datatable getting misaligned, when changing page after scrolling down a little bit

Tags: jquery, datatable

When i change the page without scrolling down vertically on current page, other page is loaded properly.
but when i change page after scrolling down somewhat, then DataTable gets misaligned
Although this misaligned dataTable gets aligned if i search something, but i do not want the datatable to get misaligned in the first place on the change of page

This is my configuration
`dTable = $("table.list").dataTable({
                    "iDisplayLength": 100,
                    "fixedHeader":true,
                    "sScrollX": "100%",
                    "sScrollY": "440px",
                    "aaSorting": [[3,'asc']],
                    "columns": [
                                null,null,null,null,null,
                                { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
                                { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: 'string' },{ "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: 'string' },
                                { "orderDataType": "dom-select" },{ "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: 'string' },
                                { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: 'string' },{ "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: 'string' },
                                { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: 'string' },{ "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: 'string' },
                                { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: 'string' },{ "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: 'string' }
                            ],
                    "columnDefs": [
                                    { "type": "num-html", targets: 4 },
                                    { "type": "num-html", targets: 5 }
                                ],
                    "fixedColumns":{
                        leftColumns: 4
                    },
                    "autoWidth":true,
                    'responsive':true
                });`

Answer (score 0):

I do not the cause of the bug, but the solution or hack which helped me is
`dTable.on("page.dt",handlePageChange);
function handlePageChange(){
 document.querySelector(".dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody").scrollTop=0;
}`

Explanation:
1. This function will be called before changing the page in datatable, and on click of pagination buttons
2. before changing page, make the scrollTop of the dataTable body = 0;